# How to change toast message's default icon in jetpack compose?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-toast

I have a toast message in my code and it shows when user enter empty dictionary name but there is a problem for me toast shows message with a default android icon and I don't want this. How can I change this icon or remove in jetpack compose kotlin ?

here is screen shot.
[image]

**Hear is my code**

```
 fun updateDictionary(context: Context, dictionaryName: String): Boolean {

        if (dictionaryName.isEmpty()) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Please Enter The Dictionary Name !", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()

            return false
        }

        val dictionary = OwnDicEntity(dictionaryName, dicCreationTime ?: "", dicId)
        updateDicUseCase.updateDic(dictionary)

        return true

    }
```

if I want to update dictionary , I go to the update screen and this function is triggered and I have to write `update dictionary name` if I enter empty dictionary name. it shows toast message as I wrote above.

I'm returning a boolean value, true and false, so that it doesn't update when I enter a empty value.

Comment: would be possible for you to share the code snippet you wrote? just to quickly diagnose where the problem is

Comment: okey I edited my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Starting with Android 12](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12#toast-redesign) you don't get any control over how Toasts look - you get two lines of text and your application icon, so the user knows where the Toast came from. (Android 11 still allows for a custom view, but only for apps in the foreground.)

If you want to *change* the icon, you need to add a new one for your app - the one you're seeing is the default `ic_launcher` drawable for a new project. [Some info about that here](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio?hl=en).

If you want to *remove* the icon, you can't! Since you seem to be displaying this as a popup in your own app, you might want to consider a [Snackbar](https://m2.material.io/components/snackbars) instead, or [setting the error hint on a text field](https://m2.material.io/components/text-fields/android#using-text-fields), or maybe create an area of your UI dedicated to displaying any errors (e.g. if there are multiple components you need to validate, and you want the error state in one place).

Comment: I came here to essentially say the same thing. I will add that in Android 11, the method is to call `setView(view: View)` on the Toast object once created. This will generate deprecation warnings. As @cactustictacs says, you should consider a Snackbar, as you can style it however you'd like.

Comment: okey I understand so when I change the my app icon toast icons are going to change. Am I right ?